# How do I set Cocoa NSLevelIndicatorCell values?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a tableview.  One of the columns in the tableview uses an NSLevelIndicatorCell.

I want to be able to allow the user to edit the warn and critical values for the level indicator such that when they enter a value into a a "warning level" textbox, it changes the warn value of the level indicators being displayed in ALL of the tableview's rows.

I am very much a newbie with Objective-C so all I can figure out so far is that I must need a delegate method to watch the textbox BUT if I succeed in doing that, how on earth do I send the new value to the particular tableview column so that the update happens to ALL of the rows (i.e. how do I send what message to the tableview and target a cell within a column within a tableview)?

Here is the code to the solution I came up with should anyone need it.

```
- (IBAction)setWarningLevel:(id)sender {
    double v;
    NSScanner *ns = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[warnLevel stringValue]];
    [ns scanDouble:&v];
    [levelIndicator setWarningValue:v];
}
```

Comment: Probably a bit much - have a look at my answer for a simpler way.

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook case for using [Cocoa bindings](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/CocoaBindings.html). Just bind the value of the text field to the `NSLevelIndicatorCell` in your table view (do that in Interface Builder). The updates should happen automagically.

I *think* it should apply for all the cells in the table view if you apply the binding to the cell in IB. However if it doesn't, you will need to write a couple lines of code that set up the binding every time a new row in the table is created. That link above will explain everything in detail, but basically you will be setting up a Key-Value Observer relationship in code between the text field and the instance of the level indicator in the row being created.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help.

While I was waiting, hopefully for a reply, I managed to figure it out myself (I am still in shock that I figured it out - I have only been coding Objective-C for 2 days).  And yes, it DOES automagically apply to all rows!

Here is my solution (in case it helps anyone):
- (IBAction)setWarningLevel:(id)sender{
 double v;
 NSScanner *ns = [NSScanner scannerWithString:[warnLevel stringValue]];
 [ns scanDouble:&v];
 [levelIndicator setWarningValue:v]; 
}

Comment: Hey, you might want to add your solution to your question itself since no one can read that unformatted mess of code you put in your comment. =)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have overdone it.

NSTextField subclasses NSControl, so you need to look in the docs for NSControl for a useful function.

Try re-writing it like this; assuming you're taking the value from a warnLevel textfield.

```
- (IBAction)setWarningLevel:(id)sender {
    double v = [warnLevel doubleValue];
    [levelIndicator setWarningValue:v];
}
```

Although this is usually shortened to this;

```
- (IBAction)setWarningLevel:(id)sender {
    [levelIndicator setWarningValue:[warnLevel doubleValue]];
}
```

You should probably have some validation that the textfield has a valid number. If you're only choosing a couple of numbers have a look at using a stepper control.

Usually, with Cocoa, if you feel like you're jumping through too many hoops, there is sometimes an easier way.

Usually ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Definitely an improvement.  

I am still in my learning curve with Objective-C (I only just started working with it last Sunday) and it is always a big chore to learn what is available in a new language (i.e. I know what I want to do, I know how I would do it in C or Pascal or PHP but what the heck does Objective-C call it?).

I'll get there eventually!!